# Odd Compilation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I am getting some strange compile issues with my application.
Sometimes when i compile my application i get a compile error. Other times the application will build and run and then when i try and navigate around the site i get a compilation error at runtime.

> Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'Workers' does not contain a definition for 'BuildADataTableOfWorkersActiveInAPeriod'

But i can assure you it does. This error doesn't happen all the time, only occasionally, but enough to be annoying.

`Workers` is a public class and `BuildADataTableOfWorkersActiveInAPeriod` is a method that returns a datatable.

Using VS2005, C#, .Net 2.5, ASP.Net on an XP Pro machine all up to date.

Comment: Not enough info to be answered. For instance, what is `Workers`?

Comment: Clean your solution and rebuild.

Comment: Updated the original post. A rebuild fixes the issue but then it will come back again.

Comment: Do you possibly have an old version of the DLL which `Workers` belongs to lying around somewhere? Try clearing out your deployment folder

Comment: Are you using code generation to create the method?